# Convert/Cast string to integer via YQL?

Tags: yql

In SQL, you can use cast or convert to convert a string to an integer so you can compare numerical values, i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE CAST(col1 AS int) < 100
```

Is it possible to do the same thing in YQL?

The following doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM json WHERE url='url_goes_here' AND CAST(col1 AS int) < 100
```

It gives me 0 results.  I should be getting more.

In both queries, col1 is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YQL is not exactly SQL per say. It is a "SQL like" language. It does not query a database instead in the background makes REST calls to the backends.

Since I don't know what table you are querying, from what I understood from the question, what you are saying can be achieved. Read the yql doc [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/filters.html#boolean). Sample query `select * from local.search where query="sushi" and location="san francisco, ca" and Rating.TotalRatings < "12"`

I know its strange that we are comparing against a string value but it does work. You can test this on the YQL console [here](http://tinyurl.com/pukamho) (just copy paste the query in the text box). Let me know if you have any questions/concerns. I will try to answer it to best of my knowledge.